# Add confidence intervals to GLM allEffects plot

Tags: glm, confidence-interval

I need to add 95% confidence intervals on my glm plot.

When I do `multiline=T` (because I need my 2 treatments on the same plot, so I did this), the intervals disappear. How can I get them back?

This is what I have now:

```
plot(allEffects(fit1), ylab= "Age of onset of foraging", main="",
     type="rescale", multiline=T, rescale.axis=F)
```

as data I have -RFID is the technique to identify the honeybees and follow their movements; 2 treatments:  control and a pathogen-treatment; "first.trip" - days until their first foraging trip. This (first/trip) is am intersted in and for which I need the 95% confidence intervals on my allEffectsplot..

```
RFID = 01 0c 1d 1e 1f
colony = A  A  A  B  B
treatment = control DWV control control DWV  
first.trip = 19 NA NA 17 17 17
last.trip = 22  NA NA 17 31 30
```

Comment: Formatting and grammar.

Comment: reproducible example please?

Comment: the confidence limits always dissapear when you set multiline to 'F', so as reproducible example you could use any dataset of R of your choice:)

Is there a way of adding them in the multiline=F plot?

Comment: do  you mean that the CIs disappear when you use `multiline=TRUE` ... ??

Answer (score 3):

From `?plot.eff`:

> ci.style: confidence bounds can be indicated using error bars, using
>             lines or confidence bands, depending on the plot type.  ... For multiline plots, the default is
>             ‘"none"’ for no confidence bounds, but style ‘"bars"’ or
>             ‘"bands"’ can also be used.

Using an example from `?plot.eff`:

```
library(effects)
mod.cowles <- glm(volunteer ~ sex + neuroticism*extraversion,
         data=Cowles, family=binomial)
eff.cowles <- allEffects(mod.cowles, xlevels=list(extraversion=seq(0, 24, 6)),
         given.values=c(sexmale=0.5))
plot(eff.cowles, 'neuroticism:extraversion',multiline=TRUE,
     ci.style="band")
```

[image]