# plot allEffects confidence intervals into one panel

Tags: r, plot, confidence-interval

I am trying to plot in only one panel the lines and confidence intervals of my linear mixed model, but I get 2 panels. How do I change this?

f is a factor with 2 levels,
c is a continuous variable

If I use multiline=TRUE, I loose the confidence intervals, which I need.

```
 mymodel = lmer(depvar ~ f*c+ (0 + f+c|pp) + (1|stim), data = datafile2)

 allEffects(mymodel)# call the particular model you want to see all the effect of
 plot(allEffects(mymodel))
```

Comment: Can you please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I have just realised that I created a duplicate. Here is the solution: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472203/add-confidence-intervals-to-glm-alleffects-plot). So we need to add `multiline=TRUE,
     ci.style="band"`

Comment: this question can't be closed as a duplicate of that one because that question doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer (hint, hint ...)